# Calling variables with f-string inside concat for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I am trying to combine dataframes using `pd.concat`.

I have 7 models, divided into 2 depending on year (2021 and 2022) so in total I have 14 dataframes each containing 4 columns. They can be created by the following command:

```
concat_list = ['expert_2021', 'expert_2022', 'forecast_168_2021', 'forecast_168_2022', 
               'forecast_24_2021', 'forecast_24_2022', 'forecast_custom_2021', 'forecast_custom_2022', 
               'forecast_lear_2021', 'forecast_lear_2022', 'forecast_standard_2021',
               'forecast_standard_2022', 'auto_2021', 'auto_2022'] 
n = 14
df_list = [pd.DataFrame({"Price_REG1":[], "Price_REG2":[], "Price_REG3":[], "Price_REG4":[]}) for x in range(n)]

for i, j in zip(concat_list, range(14)):
    locals()[i] = df_list[j]
```

Now, I want to combine these into 8 new dataframes, each representing 1 year and 1 column so 2 years * 4 columns = 8. I want to do this in a for loop. I am using f-strings to loop over the years and the columns to place the dataframes inside a list.

```
year_list = [2021, 2022]
prediction = []
for p in year_list:
    for j, s in zip(range(1,5), range(4)):
        a = pd.concat([f'forecast_24_{p}.Price_REG{j}', f'forecast_168_{p}.Price_REG{j}', 
                       f'forecast_standard_{p}.Price_REG{j}', f'forecast_custom_{p}.Price_REG{j}', 
                       f'expert_{p}.Price_REG{j}', f'forecast_lear_{p}.Price_REG{j}', 
                       f'auto_{p}.Price_REG{j}'], axis=1)
        prediction.append(a)
```

This gives me `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

So, I understand that the strings is the problem. But my question is if there is a way to make these strings to call the dataframes, or if there is some other alternative solution to this kind of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a dict to store the dataframes. The dataframes names would be the keys. Those are strings, and can be formatted like you do now. That also avoids using `locals()[i]` (in fact, `locals()` would be the dict).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I heard using `locals()[]` isn't best practise. I will try to apply this method to my workflow instead. I have placed the dfs inside a dict now and I can call the dataframe inside the dict with `df_dict['forecast_24_2021']`. But I can't manage to call the column inside the dataframe. `df_dict['forecast_24_2021.Price_REG1']` doesn't work.

Comment: Simply use `df_dict['forecast_24_2021'].Price_REG1`, or `df_dict['forecast_24_2021']['Price_REG1']`. The dot-attribute syntax is a convenience syntax, for interactive work in e.g. a notebook, but if you're doing this kind of thing, with multiple dataframes, it's better to stick to the `[column_name]` style, since that allows variables; the dot syntax only allows fixed names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `globals()` to get your dataframes:

```
year_list = [2021, 2022]
prediction = []
for p in year_list:
    for j, s in zip(range(1,5), range(4)):
        df_list2 = [globals()[f'{prefix}_{p}'][f'Price_REG{j}']
                        for prefix in ['forecast_24', 'forecast_168', 'forecast_standard', 
                                       'forecast_custom', 'expert', 'forecast_lear', 'auto']]
                
        a = pd.concat(df_list2, axis=1)
        prediction.append(a)
```

**Note**: you can't use `locals()` here because the scope is the list comprehension and you won't be able to access your dataframes.